# codeigniter number of files loaded on page request

Tags: php, codeigniter

How many `*.php` file are loaded on a single page request in CodeIgniter?

Say, we are using default welcome controller that comes along with CodeIgniter, which includes no model, how may core plus config plus database driver files are loaded on a single page request?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

Comment: perfect! @CBroe , thats what i was looking for !!!

Comment: OK, added this as answer.

Comment: Once you figure it out I am curious if my guess was right =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP function [get_included_files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) to get a list of all files included/required so far at runtime.

So if you put that into your controller, you can get the list of files included up until then.

Comment: ok, so lets say the views are loaded at last, so can i get all number of files by putting it in my view file ?

Comment: That should work, yes. PHP does not “care” about the MVC model – wherever you call that function, it should give you all includes files used up until then. (But keep in mind though, that the framework might perhaps use other mechanism than include/require to load files, so you won’t get those with this function.)